# How to disable default keyboard layout shorcut in OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

When I select the "Simplified Pinyin" layout in Mac OS X 10.8, the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> is assigned to "Display smileys" (see screenshot below).

[image]

However, since this is a French keyboard, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> is normally to print the number 6, which means I can no longer type this number.

Is there any way to disable or change this keyboard shortcut?

**Edit:**

I've tried reassigning the menu item to a different shortcut but that didn't work:

[image]

Is there any other way to change or remove this shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the shortcuts from the keyboard preference pane:

[image]

In 10.9 the Show Punctuation and Show Facemarks menu items were combined into a single item that has option-shift-B as the shortcut.

On some keyboards you can also insert 6 by pressing fn-O.

Comment: I've just tried this but unfortunately it didn't work (see updated post).

Comment: @Laurent Did you try typing at least one character using the Pinyin input method? New shortcuts seem to be registered only after the input method is used.

Comment: Yes thanks, it's working now. It looks like I needed to restart my computer for it to work.